# Is it possible to contract a computer virus via telnet?

Tags: virus, telnet

In the past there were many applications and also games where you could connect to via telnet.

Back then viruses were not THAT far spread and used as they are now. What I'm wondering about is: Nowadays you can contract computer viruses by running the wrong file, visiting the wrong page, or opening the wrong mail. IS it also possible to contract a virus via telnet by just contacting the "wrong" address? 
*(thus instead of the game server (MUD as example) you connect to a program that transmits a virus to your pc without you knowing).*

Comment: You could contract a virus by simply turning your computer on. What you are asking is if telnet is absolutely secure from malicious attack. And the answer is obviously no. There could be bugs, zero day exploits, etc. so regardless even if the technology is supposedly “secure” there are always possibilities.

Comment: You are not going to infect your machine by simply making a telnet connection.

Comment: There were viruses in the days of telnet being predominant (instead of SSH) and there were no viruses conveyed via telnet. That doesn’t mean there might not be some kind of exploit, but I highly doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

The "typical" computer virus needs to be executed in order to infect your machine.  Telnet does not execute data, it merely sends it back and forth.  For all intents and purposes, you are safe using telnet.

However, one cannot say it is *impossible* to get a virus or malware through the use of telnet.  It is possible you are using an old telnet client with a known buffer overflow exploit, which would allow a remote machine to execute code on your machine.  I am not saying this has been done, but it is *possible*.  In the end, *anything* is possible, albeit highly unlikely.

Comment: tnx. meant exactly that: If telnet (exploits aside) does only send/receive or can also brought to execute data)